# React Native 0.50.4 IOS Release crashes - works in debug mode

Tags: ios, react-native

React native Ios relase app crashes when taking a build using `react-native run-ios --configuration Release`. But it's working fine in debug mode. This is the error log:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you send us all the error log?

Comment: Same issue. iOS and Android release crashed. 